# kusto - How to add row if doesnt exists in result table from kusto query?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there any way, how to add row/rows if not exists in the result table from kusto query ?
I need to create report from application insights and I must to get table with next format:

| name_column | count |
| --- | --- |
| X | 58 |
| Y | 9 |
| Z | 15 |

X, Y, Z I get from app logs but not every time X, Y, Z are in logs.
Sometimes Z or Y or X are dont exists in logs and I get table, for example:

| name_column | count |
| --- | --- |
| X | 58 |
| Y | 9 |

I need add row with name_column "Z" and with count "0" and my correct result table should be:

| name_column | count |
| --- | --- |
| X | 58 |
| Y | 9 |
| Z | 0 |

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Per StackOverflow guidelines, a post should contain only a single question. Please open a new post for your second question.

Comment: Azure Data Explorer is Kusto as a PaaS. Azure Application Insights is a SaaS service that uses Kusto as its backbone database. It makes no sense to tag this post with both of them. Kusto Explorer is a Windows client tool for KQL, and it has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let YourQueryResults = datatable(name_column:string, count:int)["X", 58, "Y", 9];
let NameColumn = datatable(name_column:string)["X", "Y", "Z"];
NameColumn
| lookup YourQueryResults on name_column 
| extend count = coalesce(['count'], 0)
```

| name_column | count |
| --- | --- |
| X | 58 |
| Y | 9 |
| Z | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVGIzC8tCixNLaoMSi0uzSkpVrBVSEksAcKknFSNvMTc1Pjk/JzS3Dyr4pKizLx0HYXk/NK8EqvMvBLNaKUIJR0FUwsdBaVIIMMy1pqXKwdopB9QlzNYEwHDoCaAdStFKYH0I/TyctUo5OTnZ5cWYLoxP08ByTQFkNLUipLUvBSI64DWJucn5qQWJ6dqRKuDhdRjdRQMNAEr/6KN8QAAAA==)